# Merge two responses

Tags: java, callback, okhttp, spring-restcontroller, completable-future

The `firstResponse` and `secondResponse` should be combined into `CombinationBothResponses` and returned when the GET endpoint `127.0.0.1:8081/comb` is called. However, the correctly combined response is returned on the first call:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit ...",
    "bodySecondResponse": "est rerum tempore ..."
}
```

But only the firstResponse is returned on all further calls:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit ...",
    "bodySecondResponse": null
}
```

How can it be achieved that the combined response is always returned?

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @Autowired Service service;

    @GetMapping("/comb")
    public CompletableFuture<CombinationBothResponses> combine() {
        CompletableFuture<CombinationBothResponses> resultCallback = new CompletableFuture<>();
        service.sendTwoRequests(resultCallback);
        return resultCallback;
    }
}
```

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class Service {
    private final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    public void sendTwoRequests(CompletableFuture<CombinationBothResponses> resultCallback) {
        // 1. Send GET request 1
        Request firstRequest =
                new Request.Builder().url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").build();
        client.newCall(firstRequest).enqueue(new firstCallback(resultCallback));

        // 2. Send GET request 2
        Request secondRequest =
                new Request.Builder().url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2").build();

        resultCallback.thenAccept(
                firstResponse -> {
                    client.newCall(secondRequest).enqueue(new secondCallback(resultCallback));
                });
    }
}
```

```
public class firstCallback implements Callback {
    private final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
    private final CompletableFuture<CombinationBothResponses> resultCallback;

    public firstCallback(CompletableFuture<CombinationBothResponses> resultCallback) {
        this.resultCallback = resultCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
        var firstResponse = jsonb.fromJson(response.body().string(), CombinationBothResponses.class);
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            resultCallback.complete(firstResponse);
        } else {
            resultCallback.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
        resultCallback.completeExceptionally(e);
    }
}
```

```
public class secondCallback implements Callback {
    private final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
    private final CompletableFuture<CombinationBothResponses> resultCallback;

    public secondCallback(CompletableFuture<CombinationBothResponses> resultCallback) {
        this.resultCallback = resultCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
        var secondResponse = jsonb.fromJson(response.body().string(), CombinationBothResponses.class);
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            // 3. Combine firstResponse and secondResponse to the final response of the REST
            // controller
            resultCallback.thenApply(
                    firstResponse -> {
                        firstResponse.setBodySecondResponse(secondResponse.getBody());
                        System.out.println(firstResponse.getBodySecondResponse() != null); // true
                        return firstResponse;
                    });
        } else {
            resultCallback.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
        resultCallback.completeExceptionally(e);
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CombinationBothResponses {
    private int userId;
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String body;

    private String bodySecondResponse;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `resultCallback.complete(firstResponse);` in the `firstCallback`, you complete the request initiated in the controller.

Why the first time the answer is correct may depends on how quickly the first request complete the first time before the code reach `thenApply` on the `secondCallback`. (and after, maybe cache makes the first request completes faster and the code has no time to reach the `thenApply`).

You need to split the two requests in method that returns a `CompletableFuture` each, then, use `thenApply` or `thenCombine` on a higher level to chain both requests.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [similar answe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72966914/how-to-query-same-table-with-same-parameter-but-with-different-where-conditions/72970759#72970759)r i have provided before.

Create 2 different completable supplier and then combine both of them and return the final composed object.

Eg:

```java
//Async supplier for the api calls
CompletableFuture<ResponseType1> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> method(returnSyncResponseType1);
CompletableFuture<ResponseType2> cf2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> returnSyncResponseType2);

//composing result for these async supplier
CompleteableFuture.allOf(resp1, resp2).thenApply(new ComposedResponse(cf1.join, cf2.join));
```