# How to query same table with same parameter but with different where conditions and get combined result at last

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a global search I will search with one keyword but need to get results with all the matching columns of a table.

```
Page<A> a = null;
a = zRepo.getResultByNameSearch(searchText)
a = zRepo.getResultByNumberSeach(searchText)
a = zRepo.getRsultByProjectSearch(searchText)

@Query("select * from a_table x where x.name like :searchText")
Page<A> getResultByNameSearch(@Param("searchText") String searchText, Pageable pageable);

@Query("select * from a_table where x.number like :searchText")
Page<A> getResultByNumberSearch(@Param("searchText") String searchText, Pageable pageable);

@Query("select * from a_table where x.project like :searchText")
Page<A> getResultByProjectSearch(@Param("searchText") String searchText, Pageable pageable);
```

So each repository call queries and fetches the same table but according to the `searchText`.

Let's assume `name = "Company910"`, `number = "XX910"`, `project = "910"`.

Now I'm searching for `"910"` and want to get results with all the 3 values. `Page<a>` will be having all the columns of `a_table` with the list of results as per `"Company910"`, `"XX910"`, `"910"`.

How to implement this or is there any other way where I can maintain a single query instead of three different for name, number and project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of how to get the combined result. I will do something like this.

- Create repository interface as you wrote but using spring data jpa intead of raw query
- user CompletableFuture with each method call
- combine the result into a dto
- return this combined result

```java
@Repository
public interface SampleDocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<SampleDocument, Integer> {

    Page<SampleDocument> findByNameContains(String name, Pageable pageable);

    Page<SampleDocument> findByNumberContains(String number, Pageable pageable);

    Page<SampleDocument> findByProjectContains(String project, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Service class where result are combined together

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SampleDocumentService {
    private final SampleDocumentRepository repository;


    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public CompletableFuture<ResultDto> search(String query) {
        PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(0, 20);
        CompletableFuture<Page<SampleDocument>> nameSearch = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> repository.findByNameContains(query, page));
        CompletableFuture<Page<SampleDocument>> numberSearch = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> repository.findByNumberContains(query, page));
        CompletableFuture<Page<SampleDocument>> projectSearch = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> repository.findByProjectContains(query, page));
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(nameSearch, numberSearch, projectSearch)
                .thenApply(unused -> new ResultDto(nameSearch.join(), numberSearch.join(), projectSearch.join()));
    }
    
}
```

Then the call from the service

```
@GetMapping("/search")
    public CompletableFuture<ResultDto> search(@RequestParam("query") String query) {
        return service.search(query);
    }
```

call using your query argument

```http
http://localhost:8080/sample/search?query=hello
```

To answer the second part, if you want to check if the query is present in any of the columns you can write JPA query combining the `Or` operator like this.

```java
Page<SampleDocument> findByNameContainsOrNumberContainsOrProjectContains(String name, String number, String project, Pageable pageable);
```

Caller would be something like this

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public CompletableFuture<ResultDto> searchAll(String query) {
        PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(0, 20);
        CompletableFuture<Page<SampleDocument>> nameSearch = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                repository.findByNameContainsOrNumberContainsOrProjectContains(query, query, query, page));
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new ResultDto(nameSearch.join(), null, null));
    }
```

If you want to use Async with spring data and completable please follow this [link](https://www.humansreadcode.com/spring-data-completablefuture/)